# what's the matter with my dual system load?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, grub2

I just installed ubuntu 12.04.I know what I did,that is I divided the drive considering a dual system load.But,no grub stripes lighten up as booting,that means I can't selected which system I wanna go,then,I directly go onto ubuntu.

PS:the other system is WIN8,I don't think it would matter.

Answer (score 1):

Boot into ubuntu.And press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal.Then run the below command in terminal to update your grub.

```
sudo update-grub
```

After that reboot your pc,now you will see `Windows 8` partition on grub menu.

Answer (score 0):

Boot into ubuntu using Test ubuntu from the instalation CD then update the grub from sudo as told in the other comment.

Comment: the DVD doesn't get the Test function.updating grub doesn't work,unluckily.